# SWIG: Passing a 2d numpy array to a C function f(double a[])

Tags: python, c, numpy, swig, libwcs

I'm using SWIG with numpy.i to expose a C library to python. The function I'm trying to wrap takes a series of `double` arrays as arguments:

```
int wcsp2s(struct wcsprm *wcs, int ncoord, int nelem, const double pixcrd[], double imgcrd[], double phi[], double theta[], double world[], int stat[]);
```

where some of the arrays are actually two-dimensional, with the extent given by the `ncoord` and `nelem` arguments. It's these two-dimensional arrays I'm having trouble with, since `numpy.i` only seems to support things of the form `int n1`,`int n2`,`double * arr` or various permutations (and my C function does not want those extra integers), or `double arr[ANY][ANY]`. The latter looked promising, as a multidimensional C array is just a contiguous block of memory, and so should be compatible with what the function expects. But when I try

```
%apply (double INPLACE_ARRAY2[ANY][ANY]) {(double imgcrd[]),(double world[])};
```

SWIG (or rather gcc running on SWIG's output) complains:

```
wcs_wrap.c:3770:7: error: expected expression before ‘,’ token
```

Here SWIG has generated invalid C code for those arguments.

Is what I'm trying to do here possible? I guess I could use %inplace and %rename to create a wrapper function that does take in the (unnecessary) dimensions of the arrays, and then calls the real function. Even better than the approach above with inplace arrays would be if I could return these arrays as output arguments (their dimensions are easy to calculate based on `ncoord` and `nelem`.

Or perhaps a fast (i.e. not the one in astLib) python interface to libwcs already exists, so I don't have to do this?

Edit: I just discovered [pywcs](https://secure.thameswater.co.uk/tw/common/js/forms_validations.js) (which has such an obvious name that i should have found it during my initial search), which solves my underlying problem.

Edit2: I guess a wrapper that takes in a 2d numpy arrays ans passes on a flattened view of it would get around the problem, since 1d arrays seem to work. Still, that ends up requiring a large amount of files for a simple wrapper (.i, _wrap.c, .py from swig and an additional .py to further wrap the SWIG functions to fix the dimensionality problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also missing a good cookbook for using `numpy.i`. As far as I understand, you can either:

- pass arrays of dynamic size, where you pass the dimensions as function parameters as well.  If your function behaves differently, write a wrapper (e.g., `IN_ARRAY2` or `INPLACE_ARRAY2`).
- pass arrays of fixed size (e.g., `IN_ARRAY2` or `INPLACE_ARRAY2`).
- When returning arrays (e.g., `ARGOUT_ARRAY1`), you have to pass the size when calling it from python. In the example below, you would write `oo = func3(20)`. The reason seems to be since python needs to allocate the memory, it needs to know about the size,

For example, your `.i`-file could look like his:

```
...
%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
  import_array();
%}

// Pass  array of dynamic size:
%apply (double* INPLACE_ARRAY2, int DIM1, int DIM2) {(double *xx, int xx_n, int xx_m)};
void func1(double *xx,int xx_n, int xx_m);

// Pass array of fixed size:
%apply (int *INPLACE_ARRAY2[ANY][ANY]) { (double yy[4][4]) };
void func2(double yy[4][4]);

// Return a dynamic 1D array:
%apply (double* ARGOUT_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(double* out, int out_n)}
void func3(double* out, int out_n);
```

Of course you can combine these - check [the Docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/swig.interface-file.html#using-numpy-i) for more information

Comment: So the conclusion is that since arrays of fixed size are basically never used, there is no way to pass a multidimensional array via SWIG without either also passing all the lengths or by writing a wrapper for every such function? When I used the [ANY] syntax for the variable-length 1D arrays where I didn't care about the length (because it is known through other means), was that an abuse of SWIG syntax?

Comment: As far I understand it 2D [ANY][ANY] does not work - It could be that the 1D case is different (like C strings). What you cannot to is pass a numpy 2D array and get a 1D array in C++. Use ´´numpy.ravel()`` to flatten your array in python

Comment: Very well. I don't understand why not, since a 2d array and a 1d array are just different ways of viewing the same flat memory block. But I can live with ravel.

Comment: How can double* xx be used as a 2D array? Shouldn't that be double** xx?